# Is it reasonable to expect an expl3-compatible release of TikZ/PGF in the future? / Workarounds for using TikZ under expl3 syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, catcodes

Keeping in mind:

- TikZ uses space tokens significantly, and
- `expl3` syntax completely disregards whitespace and will only become more prevalent,

is it reasonable to expect a future version of TikZ where `expl3` syntax is taken into account? It would obviously be catastrophic if its syntax changed, but is it feasible to do this 'behind the scenes'?

If it is not feasible (I really don't have a good grasp on on TikZ), is there a workaround that does not litter the environment with `~`?

---

#### Edit for Christian:

They should only be visible to package-writers on the programming layer. Under `\ExplSyntaxOn`, keys like `current page.south west` and `remember picture` 'compress' to `currentpage.southwest` and `rememberpicture` respectively. Obviously these keys aren't defined, thus an error. It's only an absolute headache inside a new definition, where catcodes cannot be effectively changed with a simple `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Sometimes also the `:` with catcode letter can be a problem with TikZ. In practice I found using `\ExplSyntaxOff` and `\ExplSyntaxOn` again the easiest way (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13200713#13200713)

Comment: The choice made by the developers of `pgfkeys` to allow spaces in key names is disputable; but it's not the only point where there's conflict: parsing of TikZ commands is very dependent on spaces anyway. However this is not a concern at the user level, where `\ExplSyntaxOff` holds. It's quite difficult to program in `expl3` using TikZ constructs, but the two (sub)languages really belong to different levels.

Comment: The hobby package uses both PGF and LaTeX3 without difficulty, so I'm not sure what the potential problems are.  As egreg says, they belong on different levels.

Comment: @egreg As in `expl3` serving the *programming* layer where TikZ belongs to a presentation layer, not necessarily at the user level?

Comment: @SeanAllred Yes, that's the idea. There *will* be an intermediate level between the programming and user levels, or at least this is how I interpret Frank's plans.

Comment: Could you stress the point if and where compatibility issues arise? Are these visible to end-users or are they merely visible to package writers?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger See edit.

Comment: @SeanAllred On the other hand if a package doesn't do too much TikZ writing `current~ page.south~ west` isn't really too hard IMHO

Comment: @cgnieder It isn't, but it is a little annoying for complex uses; my use case here is a customized re-implementation of `moderntimeline`. That, and I've no idea what damage `:` could cause, as you bring up.

Comment: @SeanAllred I solved the colon issue for myself with `\tl_const:Nx  \c_<module>_colon_tl { \token_to_str:N : }` and using `\c_<module>_colon_tl` where needed.

Comment: spaces in keys like spaces in filnames always look odd to me anyway, `current~page.south~west` looks fine to me (you don't need to use both a tilde and a space)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the most sensible answer is 'no' for a couple of reasons.

First, expecting `pgf`/TikZ to cover arbitrary category code changes is probably not realistic and is a potentially ongoing battle. While `expl3` syntax is one example of a significant change to category codes, it's not the only one (various `babel` options come to mind). I don't think that the TikZ team can be expected to know about all of these, and certainly not to test for all cases. (There's also the technical issue of category codes being fixed if a TikZ construct is used inside a macro or argument to a macro.)

The second reason is more to do with the point of `expl3`: part of an approach separating out different aspects to how a document is constructed. The `expl3` language is meant for 'programming', whereas while TikZ/`pgf` has a programming element it's much more at the 'document level' (or perhaps the 'design level'). As such, there should be relatively small numbers of cases where the two are interspersed. Where they are, switching `\ExplSyntaxOff` or using `~` for spaces are both workable. The issue of `:` tokens is a bit more tricky, but the LaTeX3 team knows that some better interface for creating 'altered' category code tokens is needed in `expl3` in general, which should help with this specific case once delivered.

Comment: Is there something new about this better interface in `expl3` for creating 'altered' category code tokens?