# Workaround how to use expl3 functionality in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, latex3, xparse

## What I want to do

I want to create a command `\planfigur{<edges>}{<angles>}` which draws a triangle using `TikZ`. `\planfigur` should have 2 mandatory arguments, which let me specify edges and/or angles (where a = alpha, b = beta and c = gamma) of the triangle, which are drawn in red instead of black color.

E. g. `\planfigur{ab}{bc}` draws a black triangle, where the edges a and b and the angles beta and gamma are red.

[image: planfigur]

I use `expl3` and `xparse`. I already have read ([Is it reasonable to expect an expl3-compatible release of TikZ/PGF in the future?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154905/is-it-reasonable-to-expect-an-expl3-compatible-release-of-tikz-pgf-in-the-future)), that there are problems in using `expl3` and `tikz` together (which makes sense).

So I played around and tried to outsmart `TikZ`. I had the following idea, which unfortunately doesn't work (1:0 for `TikZ` :-)). The approach is to move all `expl3` code into a new command, where I can use `\tl_if_in:nnT` to check the arguments.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3, xparse}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \__edu_planfigur_temp

\DeclareDocumentCommand \planfigurLines { m } {

  \tl_clear:N \__edu_planfigur_temp

  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {a} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw (b) -- (c);}
  }

  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {b} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw (a) -- (c);}
  }

  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {c} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw (a) -- (b);}
  }

  \tl_use:N \__edu_planfigur_temp
}

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \planfigurAngles { m } {
  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {a} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw ($(a) + (0:1)$) arc (0:40:1) ($(a) + (20:0.7)$) node {$\alpha$};}
  }
  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {b} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw ($(b) + (120:1)$) arc (120:180:1) ($(b) + (150:0.7)$) node {$\beta$};}
  }
  \tl_if_in:nnT {#1} {c} {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \__edu_planfigur_temp {\draw ($(c) + (220:1)$) arc (220:300:1) ($(c) + (260:0.65)$) node {$\gamma$};}
  }

  \tl_use:N \__edu_planfigur_temp
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \planfigur { m m } {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.65, line join=round, thick]

    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (3.37, 2.83);

    \draw (a) -- node[below] {$c$} (b) -- node[above right] {$a$} (c) -- node[above left] {$b$} (a) -- cycle;

    \draw (a) node[left] {$A$};
    \draw (b) node[right] {$B$};
    \draw (c) node[above] {$C$};

    \begin{scope}[color=red, fill=red!25, very thick]
      \planfigurLines{#1}
      \planfigurAngles{#2}
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\planfigur{ac}{a}

\end{document}
```

## Error

> ! Package pgf Error: No shape named 0:1 is known.
>
> See the pgf package documentation for explanation. Type  H  
>   for immediate help.  ...
>                                                      l.70 \planfigur{ac}{a}

Comment: I strongly suspect that the problem is due to the fact that in `expl3` then `:` has the catcode of a letter but TikZ expects it to be `other`.  One way around this is to define a token list containing a colon with catcode "other" and use that in place of the bare `:` in your code.

Comment: @LoopSpace: Yeah, that makes sense. I forgot the problem with `:`. This would also explain, why the lines (which don't contain a `:`) work without any problem. Your approach sounds promising, but I don't know how to do this. :-(

Comment: You can do `\tl_const:Nx \c_edu_colon_tl { \token_to_str:N : }` and then use `\c_edu_colon_tl` instead of `:` in coordinates. `\c_edu_colon_tl` then contains a `:` with catcode 12 (other) instead of 11 (letter).

Comment: @cgnieder: Yes, this did it! You are my hero of the day. :-) What to do with the answer? Do you want to answes the question or should I answer it with the full working code?

Comment: @dawu Your `\planfigur...` commands are not expandable, so they should be declared with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: You are right. This is only an artefact of playing around, which I forgot to remove.

Comment: For cross-linking, this is special case of [How to use colon (':') as part of tikz syntax while in \ExplSyntaxOn environment? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/501333/how-to-use-colon-as-part-of-tikz-syntax-while-in-explsyntaxon-environment) where the argument is fully expanded thus things like `\c_colon_str` works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the things `\ExplSyntaxOn` does is giving the colon category code 11 (letter) so it can be used as part of macro names. In coordinates TikZ however expects a colon with category code 12 (other).

The easiest way: you can use the predefined `\c_colon_str` instead of `:` in TikZ' coordinates.

**Original solution before `\c_colon_str` was available:**

One solution that works is defining a token list that contains only a `:` with category code 12

```
\tl_const:Nx \c_edu_colon_tl { \token_to_str:N : }
```

and then use said token list `\c_edu_colon_tl` instead of `:` in TikZ' coordinates.

---

BTW: your token list `\__edu_planfigur_temp` misses the recommended ending for a token list: `_tl`. It also misses the recommended start `\l` or `\g` which denotes if it is local or global. I'd rename it into `\l__edu_planfigur_temp_tl`.

In expl3 variables generally should start either with `\l` (local), `\g` (global) or `\c` (constant) and end with the type of variable (`_tl` for a token list, `_int` for an integer and so on).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I know about the naming conventions of `expl3`, but this example was very quick and dirty. But you are right, of course!

Comment: @dawu well, the answer is for you but also for others with a similar problem and they might not be aware of the naming convention. So it's better to repeat it. :) I'd also say it's better to follow the convention in MWEs, too: otherwise one might be tempted to get sloppy also in “real” code... :)

Comment: You are right. Should I correct it in my MWE? As you said, it would be better.

Comment: @dawu I don't think it's necessary: since I explained the convention in my answer we should be fine, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Two more possibilities

```
\newcommand*\tikzangle[2]{#1:#2}
…
\ExplSyntaxOn
\draw (0,0) -- (\tikzangle{20}{2cm});
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

and a more practical one

```
\begingroup
\lccode`\X=`\:
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \gdef\tikzangle(#1X#2){#1:#2}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\draw (0,0) -- \tikzangle(20:2cm);
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

To add the more general one, “easier to see” than cgnieder's

```
\def\othercolon{:}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\draw (0,0) -- (20\othercolon2cm);
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Also very nice, thank you! It's always interesting to find new ways how to play a trick on the syntax. :o) But I think the first one is a bit "cleaner".

Comment: Nice. This must be adapted for `arc (220:300:1)` as well but that should not be a problem :)

Comment: @dawu The cool thing about the second one is that you just need to add `\tikzangle` (or whatever name you choose) before the angle you would write in TikZ `(20:2cm)`.

Comment: @cgnieder May be defining something like `\tikzarc` similar to this one.

Comment: @Manuel IMHO `\def\othercolon{:}` should be `\newcommand*\othercolon{:}` (since this is LaTeX). My version maybe is more usable in package code (which then is *all* expl3) but I strongly disagree with »easier to see«. Once you know how to read expl3 code it's actually the other way around. The expl3 version tells you exactly what happens (provided the programmer follows the recommended practice).

Comment: The expl3 version also will always have a `:` with catcode 12 while `\def\othercolon{:}` saves `:` with whatever catcode it has (possibly 13 with `\usepackage[french]{babel}` for example). The equivalent would rather be `\newcommand\othercolon{}\edef\othercolon{\string:}`