# How to use colon (':') as part of tikz syntax while in \ExplSyntaxOn environment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, expl3, catcodes

I want to create a simple tikz style `highlight` which will draw ellipse around the object and write label at requested position. To avoid providing the font through the text argument, I've placed it directly in the tikz style.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass {article}
\RequirePackage [utf8] {inputenc}

\RequirePackage {tikz}
\RequirePackage {xparse}

\usetikzlibrary {fit}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \tl_const:Nn \c_highlight_font {\fontsize {20} {24} \selectfont \bfseries}

    % #1 Angle
    % #2 Relative position
    % #3 Text
    \tikzset
    {
        highlight/.style~n~args = 3
        {
            ellipse,
            inner~sep = 0mm,
            draw = blue,
            dashed,
            very~thick,
            label={[#2, blue]#1:\c_highlight_font #3}
        }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (node_to_highlight) [minimum~size = 1cm, draw] at (0, 0) {};
            \node (highlight) [highlight = {210}{below~left}{1}, fit = (node_to_highlight)] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end {document}
```

This code has the issue.
The colon (`:`) in the `label` definition has changed catcode because it is inside the `\ExplSyntaxOn` environment and is therefore treated as the letter, not part of the `tikz` syntax.
This ends up writing `210:1` as the label, instead of `1` at angle `210`.

I am aware of the obvious workaround:
Define tikz style outside of `\ExplSyntaxOn` environment and change `\c_highlight_font` with something like `\def\highlightFont` which can work outside of `\ExplSyntaxOn` because it doesn't have problematic `_` in the name.

I would prefer to keep LaTeX3 variables if it is possible.
**Is there a way to add some "escape sequence" or something similar to make tikz realize that `:` is part of the syntax?**

I have tried:

1. Replacing the `:` with `\c_colon_str` but it had the same result.
2. Replacing the `:` with `\char_generate:nn{58}{12}`, but it also didn't help. Neither did any other catcode for the colon (`1`-`11`,`13`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with both your attempts is that neither was expanded to generate an actual `:`<sub><sub>12</sub></sub>. This means that Ti*k*Z sees the *control sequence* `\c_colon_str` instead of its expansion, `:`<sub><sub>12</sub></sub>.

To have this working you need to expand `\c_colon_str` (I'm ignoring the `\char_generate:nn` approach because it would generate the same thing, with more effort) *before* `\tikzset` does it's thing. In general there are two ways to do what you want, but as you say in the comments, both are quite verbose.

---

The first is the good ol' `\edef\x{<stuff-to-expand>}\x`. This is provided by `expl3` under the name `\use:x`, which does as the name suggests: it does an `x`-expansion (`\edef`) in the argument, then uses it. There are two main issues with this approach: 1) *everything* is expanded, and 2) parameter tokens (`#`) need to be doubled. In your case the `label` would change from (simplified for brevity):

```latex
                 \tikzset{label={[ #2,blue] #1\c_colon_str          \c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl #3}}
```

to

```latex
\use:x{\exp_not:N\tikzset{label={[##2,blue]##1\c_colon_str\exp_not:N\c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl##3}}}
```

Note the added `\exp_not:N` before every control sequence (and every active character should also be `\exp_not:N`'ed), and the doubled `#`. You could avoid doubling hashes by either wrapping everything else in `\exp_not:n` (not `N`):

```latex
\use:x{\exp_not:N\tikzset{label={\exp_not:n{[#2,blue]#1}\c_colon_str\exp_not:n{\c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl#3}}}}
```

which is not exactly shorter. To avoid doubling the hashes you can use the `e`-type expansion instead of `x`, but there's not much else to gain from it. The `e`-type is the e-TeX primitive `\expanded` (introduced in pdfTeX and XeTeX in TeXLive 2019 and LuaTeX much earlier) or, in older distribution, an emulation of it written in `expl3` (which makes it much slower).

---

The other approach is to define a macro which takes as argument the token you want to replace. The basic idea is to do `\def\__temp:w#1{<stuff with #1>}` and `\exp_args:No\__temp:w{\c_colon_str}`, then the expansion of `\c_colon_str` will be inserted in the proper places. In your case, the `label` would change from (spaces added for clarity):

```latex
    \tikzset { label = {[##2, blue]##1 \c_colon_str \c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl ##3} }
```

to:

```latex
\cs_set_protected:Npn \__iskustvo_tmp:w #1
  { \tikzset { label = {[##2, blue]##1      #1      \c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl ##3} } }
\exp_args:NV \__iskustvo_tmp:w \c_colon_str
```

The advantage of this method is that you'll hardly run into expansion problems. The downside is that there is a whole lot of boilerplate code to define the temporary macro and use it, plus all hashes must be doubled. It's basically a matter of choice now.

---

However Ti*k*Z is not designed work under unusual catcode regimes (such as `expl3`'s), so I recommend you leave Ti*k*Z code separate from `expl3` code to avoid this kind of problem. Indeed, interfacing LaTeX3 code with LaTeX2e code is a recurrent problem, mainly due to the different catcode settings. One way to do that is to replace `_` by `@` in a variable name, so that `\c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl` becomes `\c@iskustvo@highlight@font@tl`. In fact this is done in `expl3.sty` to keep track of load-time options before loading the LaTeX3 kernel itself. My suggestion for your code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_const:Nn \c@iskustvo@highlight@font@tl {\fontsize {20} {24} \selectfont \bfseries}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% #1 Angle
% #2 Relative position
% #3 Text
\tikzset
  {
    highlight/.style n args = 3%<--
      {
        ellipse,
        inner sep = 0mm,
        draw = blue,
        dashed,
        very thick,
        label = {[#2, blue]#1:\c@iskustvo@highlight@font@tl #3}
      }
  }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (node_to_highlight) [minimum size = 1cm, draw] at (0, 0) {};
    \node (highlight) [highlight = {210}{below left}{1}, fit = (node_to_highlight)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

A side note: the convention for naming variables is `\⟨scope⟩_⟨module⟩_⟨name⟩_⟨type⟩`. `⟨scope⟩` is either `l`ocal, `g`lobal, or `c`onstant, `⟨module⟩` should be the prefix of the package your are writing or something else unique for your code, `⟨name⟩` is a descriptive name for the variable, and `⟨type⟩` is the type of the variable. In your case, it's a `c`onstant (because you used `\tl_const:Nn`), you left out a module name so I used your user name, `iskustvo`, the name of the variable is `highlight_font`, and the type is a `t`oken `l`ist variable. Putting it all together you have `\c_iskustvo_highlight_font_tl`.

Comment: Ti*k*Z works under the normal category code regime for LaTeX2e, which is the same as for plain TeX, except after `\makeatletter`. There, `:` is of category “other” (12), cf. the TeXbook p. 37.

Comment: @Iskustvo Oh, I feel stupid now ;-) But (unless you load `babel` with a language that makes `:` active, like French) the `:` is catcode `12`, as frougoun said.

Answer (score 0):

you can use my package...

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{precattl}  % ======== change 1, add the package here
\RequirePackage [utf8] {inputenc}  % side note, see [macros - What's the difference between \RequirePackage and \usepackage? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19919/whats-the-difference-between-requirepackage-and-usepackage)

\RequirePackage {tikz}
\RequirePackage {xparse}

\usetikzlibrary {fit}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes}

\ExplSyntaxOn

    \tl_const:Nn \c_highlight_font {\fontsize {20} {24} \selectfont \bfseries}

    \precattl_exec:n {
        % #1 Angle
        % #2 Relative position
        % #3 Text
        \tikzset
        {
            highlight/.style~n~args = 3
            {
                ellipse,
                inner~sep = 0mm,
                draw = blue,
                dashed,
                very~thick,
                label={[#2, blue]#1 \cO\: \c_highlight_font #3}
                % ======== change 2 ^^^^^ specify you want the colon in other catcode
            }
        }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node (node_to_highlight) [minimum~size = 1cm, draw] at (0, 0) {};
            \node (highlight) [highlight = {210}{below~left}{1}, fit = (node_to_highlight)] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end {document}
```

not specific for this case, but basically it allow specifying arbitrary catcode inside a token list, as long as there's no catcode change in the code itself it should work.