# tikz inside expl3

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong in this basic example. I want to have a function inside my expl3 code draw a simple picture with tikz, but I get an error `Package pgf Error: No shape named 0:0 is known.`

MWE

```
\documentclass{extbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc}

% my command to draw an orange rectangle with tikz
\newcommand{\drawmyshape}{
    \tikz[font=\normalsize]{
        \draw[color=orange!50, fill=orange] (0:0) -- ++(\linewidth,0) -- ++(0,-2em) -- (0,-2em) -- (0,0);
    }%%%%%
}%%%%%

\usepackage{xparse}%allows the NewDocumentCommand

\ExplSyntaxOn

%Why does the tikz code inside the expl3syntax break it? I need to be able to call this here.
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawmyshapeagain}{}{
    \tikz[font=\normalsize]{
        \draw[color=orange!50, fill=orange] (0:0) -- ++(\linewidth,0) -- ++(0,-2em) -- (0,-2em) -- (0,0);
    }%%%%%
}%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\drawmyshape

\drawmyshapeagain

\end{document}
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197083/workaround-how-to-use-expl3-functionality-in-tikz I guess.

Comment: Thank you guys for the pointer, I was having a hard time searching for something so simple!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In expl3 the colon is a letter, and this breaks the (0:0) in your code. You don't use expl3 commands in your example so the easiest is to simply remove the `\ExplSyntaxOn`  command, but if you need it for something else you can use (in this case, this doesn't work always) `\c_colon_str` :

```
\documentclass{extbook}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning,calc}

% my command to draw an orange rectangle with tikz
\newcommand{\drawmyshape}{
    \tikz[font=\normalsize]{
        \draw[color=orange!50, fill=orange] (0:0) -- ++(\linewidth,0) -- ++(0,-2em) -- (0,-2em) -- (0,0);
    }%%%%%
}%%%%%

\usepackage{xparse}%allows the NewDocumentCommand

\ExplSyntaxOn

%Why does the tikz code inside the expl3syntax break it? I need to be able to call this here.
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawmyshapeagain}{}{
    \tikz[font=\normalsize]{
        \draw[color=orange!50, fill=orange] (0\c_colon_str0) -- ++(\linewidth,0) -- ++(0,-2em) -- (0,-2em) -- (0,0);
    }%%%%%
}%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\drawmyshape

\drawmyshapeagain

\end{document}
```